# Spring Boot Banner reporting wrong java version

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

At the bottom of our `banner.txt`, we have the following

```
Running Spring Boot ${spring-boot.version} on java ${java.version} in environment ${ccic.environ}
```

which starts up with

```
Running Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE on java 1.8.0_144 in environment uat
```

We had a bit of a scare today because someone noticed it says `1.8.0_144` for the `java.version`, however we should be running  `1.8.0_131`.  After further investigation, we can confirm that we are running with `1.8.0_131`.

I was curious where `1.8.0_144` was coming from.  It seems `MANIFEST.MF` contains the value of `1.8.0_144` for the key `Build-Jdk`, presumably java on the build server is wrong.  Is that were spring is reading it from?

It surprises me that `java.version` would prefer `MANIFEST.MF` over the runtime.   Am I off in my thinking?  Why is spring boot not returning the correct java version?  I tried looking in the spring source, but finding "java.version" or "javaversion" hasn't been helpful.

Comment: _java.version_ is a system property. So its part of the system where launch the build of your application. It has nothing to do with spring itself.

Comment: `${java.version}` is being interpolated by spring.  My understanding would be that it takes its value from the system property with the same name, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: just tested it out, it prints out the jre-version you server is running on. so its really the system property

Comment: So in your situation, you compiled and then ran with a different version?  I think that is what is happening with us.

Comment: Correct, compiled/build jar with *JDK 1.8.0_162*. when run with *JRE 1.8.0_181*, print on startup = *1.8.0_181*. When run with JRE *11.0.2* application prints *11.0.2* on startup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the `MANIFEST.MF` and spring were both red herrings.  We use maven for our builds and we had filtering turned on.  The builds were filtering `banner.txt` and replacing the value.  We used the following configuration to prevent the filtering from occurring to `banner.txt`.

```
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>banner.txt</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>banner.txt</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
```